# Write down a basis of $V$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and prove that it is a basis;

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a two dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and $L\in End(V)$. Let $\mathcal{A}=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ a basis of $V$, and let
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix} z_1 & z_2 \\ z_3 & z_4 \end{pmatrix}
$$
be the matrix of $L$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{A}$. Now considering $V$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space:

(a) write down a basis of $V$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and prove that it is a basis;

Is it as simple as saying $\mathcal{B} = \{e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)\}$?

(b) what is the matrix (with real entries) of $L$ now as an endomorphism of a real vector space with respect to the basis you wrote down?

If what I have for part (a) is correct,

$$ N = \begin{pmatrix} z_1 & 0 \\ 0 & z_4 \end{pmatrix} $$
a good choice?

Comment: No. First of all, $V$ is a $2$-dimensional space over $\mathbb{C}$, not over $\mathbb{R}$. Try to think what its dimension over $\mathbb{R}$ should be. Also, even if you prove it is a space of dimension $n$, you can't just take the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$. $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n}$, but not necessary equal to it.

Comment: I just used to starting with $\mathbb{R}$ and then going with $\mathbb{C}$. So $V$ is 2-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$. I can't add the entries from column 1 and 2, right?

Comment: I do want to apologize firstmost because it's the first time I am learning linear algebra using commutative algebra, which I have completely forgotten

Comment: Look, you know that $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$ is a basis over $\mathbb{C}$. Now you need to turn it into a basis over $\mathbb{R}$. Hint: try the set $\{\alpha_1, i\alpha_1, \alpha_2, i\alpha_2\}$.

Comment: I was thinking of that but thought because it has $i$'s that we couldn't have that for a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space

Comment: This is a common mistake. There is no such things as "real" or "complex" vector. $V$ is a constant space of vectors. The elements of $V$ don't suddenly change because we know work over a different field. $i\alpha_1$ and $i\alpha_2$ are regular elements of $V$, just like $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are.

Comment: Would the matrix be then $\begin{pmatrix} z_1 & z_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & iz_1 & iz_2 \\ z_3 & z_4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & iz_3 & iz_4 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: No, the matrix indeed has to contain real numbers now. Look, the first column of $M$ tells us that $L(\alpha_1)=z_1\alpha_1+z_3\alpha_2$. Writing $z_j=x_j+iy_j$ we get $L(\alpha_1)=x_1\alpha_1+y_1(i\alpha_1)+x_3\alpha_2+y_3(i\alpha_2)$. So the first column will be $(x_1, y_1, x_3, y_3)^T$. Similarly, compute the other columns. This is all about using the definitions.

Comment: Alright. So $L(i\alpha_1)= -y_1\alpha_1 + x_1(i\alpha_1) - y_3\alpha_2 + x_3(i\alpha_2)$?